Echo and Flicker
If I cast a Karmic Guide and on my opponents upkeep I use Blur to flicker it on my next upkeep, do I need to pay the echo cost? I'm under the assumption that I don't due to the rules of flickered creatures.

400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence.

So, in this case I didn't control this "new" Karmic Guide during my last upkeep so I wouldn't pay the echo right?

You have it backwards. You would pay the Echo cost during your next upkeep because you didn't control it since your previous upkeep.
The Echo ability is defined in rule 702.30a:

Echo is a triggered ability. "Echo [cost]" means "At the beginning of your upkeep, if this permanent came under your control since the beginning of your last upkeep, sacrifice it unless you pay [cost]."

In this case, the Karmic Guide came under your control during your opponent's upkeep, which is more recent than your last upkeep.

In other words, you have to pay the Echo for the "new" Karmic guide, but not for the "old" one since it's no longer on the battlefield.

Right, the "old" one doesn't exist, so its Echo ability doesn't exist. There's nothing to trigger and nothing to pay for that one.

Note to OP, you’d have it correct IF echo were a delayed trigger such as “when this enters the battlefield, at the beginning of your next upkeep sacrifice it unless you pay [cost]”.

@GendoIkari That doesn't look right to me. If a creature had such an ability, it would trigger when it reenters after being flickered, so you would still have to pay.

@GendoIkari it would have to be "when you cast [this], at the beginning of your next upkeep sacrifice it unless you pay [cost]" for flickering (or reanimation etc) to avoid the echo cost

Ah right... I almost said "when you cast this" even.

@GendoIkari It would have to trigger off of something other than ETB. For instance, Unearth gets the exile from it being cast with the Unearth cost. Also, if the permanent gets the ability from some source other than itself, that would work. For instance, if a spell says "Put a creature card from your hand onto the battlefield. At the beginning of the next upkeep, sacrifice it unless you pay [cost]", then when you flicker it, it comes back without the spell's trigger.
